# Optional argument in Extbase RouteEnhancer

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I need to add an optional argument to the url of news records (own extension).

Current enhancer configuration:

```
MyNewsSystem:
type: Extbase
extension: MyNewsSystem
plugin: News
routes:
  -
    _controller: 'News::show'
    routePath: '/detail/{news_title}'
    _arguments:
      news_title: selectedNewsItem
aspects:
  news_title:
    type: PersistedAliasMapper
    tableName: tx_mynewssystem_domain_model_news
    routeFieldName: path_segment
```

This works fine and generates the following url scheme: 
/detail/title-of-news/

Now I need to add an optional parameter to the end of the url:
/detail/title-of-news/?hl=String+with+info
Adding this parameter will end up in 404.

Is there a possibilty to just ignore that argument in my routeenhancer? Or how do I proceed?

Comment: i think that the routeFieldName is an absolute name. Have you tried to use a pattern as well? routeFieldPattern: '^(?P<path_segment>.+)' something like that? Still i am not sure if this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to extend the routeFieldName, but the routePath. So I just want to add an optional parameter to the whole url, not to a single segment of it.

Comment: in my mind, this routeFieldPattern says that you expect the path segment as defined in the database + everything that comes after that. That is the reason why i mentioned it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a `404 Not Found` because a cHash-error occured. If you generate the link through TYPO3 (e.g. with `f:link` or `typolink`) and your routing configuration is correct, a correct `?cHash=`-parameter will be appended.

If your custom parameter **does not change the HTML** output at all you can add it to the `[FE][cacheHash][excludedParameters]` (in "Installation-wide settings"). Mind that this means that different values of this parameter would all go onto the same cache entry. Thus, if you need to do anything with the parameter, your only option is JavaScript.

The other case is quite common, but I'll add all the conditions for that case:

If you need to **alter the HTML** output depending on that parameter **and** **(** you absolutely do not want a `?cHash` **or** you cannot have TYPO3 generate that link **)** **and** you cannot use the `PersistedAliasMapper` (because the parameter is free text and not bound to anything in the database) **and** you cannot use the other aspect mappers (like `StaticRangeMapper`), your only option is to write a custom Aspect.

Have a look here https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/ExtendingRouting.html - in your case I would look for inspiration in `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\StaticRangeMapper`. It is advisable to narrow down the possible values as much as possible (to prevent cache flooding, the reason why `cHash` was added to TYPO3), but you will be able to get rid of the `?cHash`.

---

Just for completeness: this is how it "should" be. There are currently some inconsistencies with cached vs. non-cached and "route-enhanced" pages (like your detail page) vs. "pagetree" pages whether or not a cHash-error is thrown. But if you treat parameters like suggested here, I would think you are safe for the future.

Comment: Thanks. I created this link with a typolink before, but it was not processed within my solr configuration. Maybe I missed something and try again. To ignore this param is quite a good idea, as this param is indeed a read only param for javascript handling (highlighting the search phrase on the target page, coming from search results listing).